# Active high SR latch when input changes from (1,0) to (0,1)

Tags: digital-logic, latch, sequential-logic

If we do analysis like in the below diagram i.e from S side, then I got outputs Qn+1=0 and (Qn+1)'=0.

But it is not supposed to happen according to state table( i.e actually Qn+1=1 and (Qn+1)'=0 must come as it is reset state).

What did I miss??

[image: scanned image of handwritten diagram of SR latch with NOR gates]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the bottom diagram - With '0' at the output of the top NOR gate you have both inputs to the bottom NOR gate at '0' and so the output of the bottom NOR gate is forced to a '1'.

Comment: yes brother i accept your case but if we do analysis in reverse i.e  the output of bottom nor gate i.e 0 is sent to top ones then the output of it(Qn+1) is zero. so why are not considering this

Comment: @KolluruYashwanth If both R & S inputs are held at '1' then indeed both outputs will be at '0'. Both inputs at '1' is referred to as an illegal condition and generally is best avoided in a circuit design. In reality this condition can be used if care is taken to make sure that R and S are not taken back to '0' simultaneously. If R & S are taken back to '0' simultaneously then the outputs will end up in an indeterminate state. One output will be '1' and one output will be '0' but we can't predict which way around it will be. So this would be a problem.